# Get the width of a rect shape

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I'm trying to get the width of a node shape in kineticjs.
I'm doing this:

```
      var node = left.find('Rect');
      var width = node.width()
      console.log(width);
```

and left is a group that has a Rect.

```
  var shape = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: C_EC_WIDTH,
    height: C_EC_WIDTH,
    fill: viewcolor,
    stroke: "black",
    strokeWidth: 1
  });

  left.add(shape);
```

But I always get this result:

[image]

I have tried getWidth(), setWidth(100), width() and width(100). The width(100) and setWidth(100) worked properly. But the others not! I can not have access to the width of the shape, I always get the object!

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

Tried this:

```
var width = node.width().width().width();
```

and have the same result. It returns the kinetic object! I have no idea why! It is not making any sense for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find()` function returns collection of objects. You may have many rectangles in container.
So should do this:

```
  var node = left.find('Rect')[0];
  var width = node.width()
  console.log(width);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had not remembered that.

Comment: Do you know what happened to the tutorials link in the kineticjs oficial page?
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-events-tutorials-introduction-with-kineticjs/

Comment: Broken. Looks like mainteiner have no time for repairing. Use archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20140410105707/http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-spline-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks @lavrton. I already have used the link you sent me. I notice that a few months ago, since the site was updated and I found strange the issue has not been solved. But yes, I understand that they have no time to do that.
Kineticjs is awesome, congratulations for the work you have done :)